# UL float left doesnt work correctly IE 6

Tags: html, css

These ul are inside a fixed size container..

```
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ΑAOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ACC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ACCP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">AJP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Anejo</a></li>
                    </ul>

                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ASCO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">British Medical Journal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Current Medical Literature</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Clinical Publishing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> EC-Europ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    and another one
```

The problem is that with IE6 they take all the container width...  Setting li to float left doesnt not take the whole width but i dont want them to go left to each other.

```
#journals-list {background: url(img/journals-background.png) ;background-repeat: no-repeat;height: 300px;width: 495px;}
#journals-list ul {float: left;margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px;display: inline;zoom:1; margin-top: 55px;}
#journals-list ul li{display: block; height: 39px; line-height: 39px;border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-color: #cc784e;border-bottom-width: 1px;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 10px;}
#journals-list ul li{background-image: url(img/journal-bullet.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: left center;}
#journals-list ul li:last-child{border-bottom-style:none;border-bottom-width:0}
#journals-list ul li a{text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;}
```

I am using mayers CSS RESET..

Comment: Could you add a link to a live site, or make a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case?

Comment: It doesn't work in Mosaic either. :S

Comment: http://jsbin.com/etuve4/5  Here is a sample.... I am forced to support ie6 and to change png to 8bit ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to one of the occasions when you *don't* want hasLayout set. The problem is the height setting on `#journals-list ul li` causes hasLayout to be set on those elements. Remove it, and the problem goes away. Add, say zoom:1, and the problem returns.

Depending on the actual data you want to present, you may get away with just removing the height style setting, and relying on the line-height setting to provide correct vertical spacing.

Comment: thank you thank you a lot... You saved me lot of hours :) The height was the problem. Now workz greatly..

Comment: there is a drawback :( Li adds a padding at left when it doesnt have layout.